# SpQuery is not returning correct values

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, list-view, custom-list

I have a view on my  custom list that filters items created by me.I deleted this filter.Even though 
in my server object model I am getting item collection created by [me] through spquery. I checked my caml query  in u2u caml builder.It returns items Perfectly.Only Problem with spquery.Any ideas.This Problem is not with query .It deals with filtered items.I am unable to see items created by others.Even though i removed filtering in view .It is filtering items on User view.Please help me

Comment: Post the SPQuery you are trying with?

Comment: <OrderBy><FieldRef Name='FWorkDate' Ascending='TRUE'/></OrderBy><Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='User'/><Value Type='User'>john</Value></Eq><And><Geq><FieldRef Name='WorkDate' /><Value Type='DateTime'>2014-11-13T16:57:01Z</Value></Geq><Leq><FieldRef Name='WorkDate' /><Value Type='DateTime'>2014-11-13T16:57:01Z</Value></Leq></And></And></Where>

Comment: @user3492718 Are you sure field name is correct.. Since in OrderBy you are giving `FWorkDate`, while in Where clause you are giving `WorkDate`.. Also Geq and Leq values are same, it's like get me values between 5 and 5, of couse there are no values in between.. Did you try changing the date ranges?

Comment: yes fields names are correct.I tested with different data ranges but no use.I am getting data on u2u caml builder.Only front end i am not getting data by server object model

Comment: I resolved my Problem by giving draft items visibility to all and removed all filters in list view.Thanks for responses

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<Where>
    <And>
        <And>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name='User'/>
                <Value Type='User'>john</Value>
            </Eq><And>
            <Geq>
                <FieldRef Name='WorkDate' />
                <Value Type='DateTime'>2014-11-13T16:57:01Z</Value>
            </Geq>
        </And>      
        <Leq>
            <FieldRef Name='WorkDate' />
            <Value Type='DateTime'>2014-11-13T16:57:01Z</Value>
        </Leq>
    </And>
</Where>
<OrderBy>
    <FieldRef Name='FWorkDate' Ascending='TRUE'/>
</OrderBy>
```

Also you should make sure the display name is `john`

Comment: No It didn't resolved my problem .

Comment: I resolved my Problem by giving draft items visibility to all and removed all filters in list view.Thanks for response